# Powershell Script auto enter -Port number

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

Hi guys I am trying to write a script >>Newbie<< and I would like to run it through task scheduler. It is a windows server update service cleanup tool. I have run the commands individually, as running them altogether seems to  not work on my server just the same as running the gui. I would like to run all procceses from the one script. After entering the command it prompts me for a -Port number, and I would like to run it silently.

```
Get-WsusServer "wus" | Invoke-WsusServerCleanup -CleanupObsoleteUpdates
```

After running this it will prompt me for a port number; which is 8530 I would like the script to enter it for me then go to the next command when complete; e.g.

```
Get-WsusServer "wus" | Invoke-WsusServerCleanup -CleanupUnneededContentFiles
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you edit this and add in text you see asking for a `-Port`?  This will help other people find your question and get this answer as well.

Comment: Bill's answer below is correct, but following the "teach a man to fish" principle you can look this information up using the `Get-Help` cmdlet.  If you type `Get-Help Get-WsusServer -full` you will be able to view a ton of information on the cmdlet, including whether or not each parameter is mandatory, and all options for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prompt appears because the `-PortNumber` parameter is mandatory and you are not specifying it. To run the cmdlet without prompting for the parameter, specify it on the command line:

```
Get-WsusServer "wus" -PortNumber 8530
```

Answer (score 0):

You could specify parameter names:

```
$WsusServer = Get-WsusServer -Name "wus" -Port 8530
$WsusServer | Invoke-WsusServerCleanup -CleanupObsoleteUpdates
$WsusServer | Invoke-WsusServerCleanup -CleanupUnneededContentFiles
```

Optionally, if you need to specify the command to use SSL:

```
$WsusServer = Get-WsusServer -Name "wus" -Port 8530 -UseSsl
$WsusServer | Invoke-WsusServerCleanup -CleanupObsoleteUpdates
$WsusServer | Invoke-WsusServerCleanup -CleanupUnneededContentFiles
```

Comment: Thanks Shawn, that has done the job, doesnt require SSL but thanks for the extra info - love ya work!